# htaccess redirect subdomain folder path to new URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a number of URLs ...

http://download.stevechab.com/album/allergy TO http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/allergy

http://download.stevechab.com/album/reallergy-remix-album TO http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/reallergy-remix-album

http://download.stevechab.com/album/vanillarabb TO http://arabbi.bandcamp.com/album/vanillarabb

http://download.stevechab.com/album/arabb TO http://arabbi.bandcamp.com/album/arabb

I've tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^download\.stevechab\.com/album/allergy [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/allergy$1 [r=301,nc]

Redirect 301 http://download.stevechab.com/album/allergy http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/allergy
```

It didn't work. I have access to the stevechab.com htaccess file but not the download.stevechab.com htaccess file. Is there any way to do this redirect?

Here's what my entire htaccess file looks like ...

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.stevechab.com

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^stevechab.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.stevechab.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

Redirect 301 http://stevechab.com http://www.stevechab.com

rewritecond %{http_host} ^download\.stevechab\.com/album/allergy [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/allergy$1 [r=301,nc]

Redirect 301 http://download.stevechab.com/album/allergy http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/allergy
```

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can only match host/domain name using `%{http_host}` variable.

You can use this rule in the root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^download\.stevechab\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(album/.+)$ http://histamines.bandcamp.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, I have other albums I'm redirecting as well ... like http://download.stevechab.com/album/vanillarabb to http://arabbi.bandcamp.com/album/vanillarabb.

Comment: ok check updated answer though you should make it clear in your question.

Comment: Done. Sorry 'bout that. So, can I add folder paths?

download\.stevechab\.com/album/allergy$

Comment: ok did you try my suggested rule yet? This should work with your stated test cases.

Comment: Not yet. Would I do this?

`RewriteCond %{http_host} ^download\.stevechab\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(album/allergy.+)$ http://histamines.bandcamp.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(album/reallergy-remix-album.+)$ http://histamines.bandcamp.com/album/reallergy-remix-album/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(album/vanillarabb.+)$ http://arabbi.bandcamp.com/album/vanillarabb/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(album/arabb.+)$ http://arabbi.bandcamp.com/album/arabb/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: No you just need one single rule as I suggested above. Just keep that rule and test all your your URLs.

Comment: Sorry, it did nothing. Thanks for all the help! Please see my updated post above. Not all redirects go to histamines.bandcamp.com

Comment: It doesn't work because your **entire htaccess** still has that old invalid rule. You need to place my suggested rule just below `RewriteEngin On` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58017/discussion-between-steve-chab-and-anubhava).